# Container spawning for interactive tutorial

Tags: linux, docker, containers, virtualization, gnu-coreutils

I want to write an interactive web tutorial for unix coreutils. I'm curious about best ways to evaluate solution submitted by student on backend. 
Name some virtualization/containerization technologies that would eliminate the possibility of security breach (user gaining access to backend server server) and with low hardware resources overhead?

Docker is on everybody's tongue but could it be utilised for this purpose?